# creating facebook comments - without using social plugin

Tags: facebook

I there any way I can create and post comments, without using comments plugin at all.

Facebook graph api allowed me to fetch all comments under a particular post, but didn't find anyway to create new ones :(

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation for the [Post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/#comments):

> **Create**
>
> You can write to the POST_ID/comments connection to post a comment to
>   the post by issuing an HTTP POST request with the publish_stream
>   permission and following parameters.

Comment: I missed that one, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Facebook don't look kindly on this kind of thing, even though OG objects have a /comments connection, so either the docs are inaccurate or it's a proper bug. Would love to believe it's the latter but I suspect it's a documentation error.

In any event i've created a bug report at [Posting to Comments Social Plugin doesn't work](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/273472902762482) in the vain hope it will be addressed, please engage on that report so we can get some love for this issue.